# x:Bind in resource dictionary doesn't work

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp, xbind, compiled-bindings

I'm struggling to get a grip of the compiled databinding concept. I have one view (MainPage) that contains a ListBox and one data template (ItemTemplate) used for that ListBox. The MainPage has a MainPageViewModel that contains an ObservableCollection of ItemViewModels. The ItemViewModel contains only one property Name.

MainPage:

```
<Page x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp">
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ItemDictionary.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items}"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Resource dictionary containing datatemplate:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="TestApp.ItemDictionary"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" x:DataType="local:ItemViewModel">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This code compiles but when I run it the binding to the Name property fails, although the items get generated. If I use a classic binding everything works fine and if I place the data template directly in the resources for the MainPage it also works. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://igrali.com/2015/06/14/how-to-use-compiled-bindings-xbind-from-a-resource-dictionary/

Comment: Bind is a compile-time construct, IIRC.  But everything in a DataTemplate is runtime--it isn't hard-coded into the window, but dynamically loaded at runtime as needed.  I don't have any references that tell me this, but I'm assuming x:Binds are not hooked up at runtime.  Switch it to a regular Binding.  It's kinda like how a StaticResoruce can be used for content available at compile time, but when you're trying to find runtime-set resources, you have to use a DynamicResource.

Comment: @Will But according to the Documentation it should work if x:DataType is declared. See [DataTemplate and x:DataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#binding_object_xbind)

Comment: That's helpful!

Comment: @Clemens thank you for the link! The problem (as far as I understand it) was that I didn't instantiate the dictionary and therefor it never ran InitializeComponent from the code behind. So the solution is: <local:ItemDictionary /> instead of <ResourceDictionary Source="ItemDictionary.xaml" /> in the MergedDictionaries...

Comment: @Clemens could you expand on your comment in the form of an answer? I found it very useful!

Answer (score 5):

Correct:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <local:ItemDictionary />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

Incorrect:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ItemDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```